# Failed to initialize JPA EntityManagerFactory: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.env.spi.JdbcEnvironment]

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jenkins, querydsl, spatial-query

My application runs properly in local environment. But in Docker(of AWS EC2) isn't working.

When I `docker logs my-spring-image`

```
2021-11-09 11:10:49.793 ERROR 7 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/locationtech/jts/geom/Geometry
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3166) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3191) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1904) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.util.ReactiveWrappers.usesReactiveType(ReactiveWrappers.java:159) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar!/:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.AbstractRepositoryMetadata.isReactiveRepository(AbstractRepositoryMetadata.java:160) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar!/:2.5.5]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.config.RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.useRepositoryConfiguration(RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport.java:366) ~[spring-data-commons-2.5.5.jar!/:2.5.5]
```

And this is my build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        queryDslVersion = "4.4.0"
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.5.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
    // querydsl
    id "com.ewerk.gradle.plugins.querydsl" version "1.0.10"
}

group = 'ssafy'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    // Web
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    // WebFlux
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux'

    // MySQL Database
    runtimeOnly 'mysql:mysql-connector-java'
    //spatial query
    compileOnly 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial'

    // JPA Hibernate
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'

    // Lombok
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testCompileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testAnnotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'

    // Spring Security
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    // java-jwt : https://github.com/auth0/java-jwt
    implementation 'com.auth0:java-jwt:3.18.2'
    // OAuth
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    // Validation
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation'

    //firebase
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-admin:6.8.1'
    // okhttp
    implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.2.2'
    // swagger
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:3.0.0'
    implementation 'io.springfox:springfox-boot-starter:3.0.0'

    // Dev Tools
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    // p6spy : https://github.com/gavlyukovskiy/spring-boot-data-source-decorator
    implementation 'com.github.gavlyukovskiy:p6spy-spring-boot-starter:1.7.1'
    // Test
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    // JsonObject 사용
    implementation group: 'com.googlecode.json-simple', name: 'json-simple', version: '1.1.1'

    //Tymeleaf
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf'
    implementation 'nz.net.ultraq.thymeleaf:thymeleaf-layout-dialect'

    // s3
    implementation('org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-aws:2.2.6.RELEASE')

    //javax
    implementation("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")
    annotationProcessor("javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.3.2")

    // querydsl
    implementation 'com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

// querydsl
def querydslDir = "$buildDir/generated/querydsl"

querydsl {
    jpa = true
    querydslSourcesDir = querydslDir
}

sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDir querydslDir
}

configurations {
    querydsl.extendsFrom compileClasspath
}

compileQuerydsl {
    options.annotationProcessorPath = configurations.querydsl
}
```

And this is application.yml

```
spring:
  profiles:
    include: API-KEY
  ## MYSQL 일 경우에
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:mysql://{ip-address}:3306/coffee_station?useSSL=false&allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&serverTimezone=UTC
    username: username
    password: password
    driver-class-name: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver

  jpa:
    database: mysql
    database-platform: org.hibernate.spatial.dialect.mysql.MySQL56InnoDBSpatialDialect
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        format_sql: true
        default_batch_fetch_size: 500
    open-in-view: false

logging.level:
  org.hibernate.SQL: debug

decorator:
  datasource:
    p6spy:
      enable-logging: true
jwt:
  secret: ---------secret key----------

cloud:
  aws:
    s3:
      bucket: bucket-name
    region:
      static: ap-northeast-2
    stack:
      auto: false
```

And this is my dockerfile

```
FROM openjdk:11-jdk AS build
WORKDIR /app

COPY gradlew .
COPY gradle gradle
COPY build.gradle .
COPY settings.gradle .
COPY src src
COPY src/main/resources/application.yml src/main/resources/application.yml
COPY src/main/resources/application-API-KEY.properties src/main/resources/application-API-KEY.properties
RUN cat src/main/resources/application.yml
RUN cat src/main/resources/application-API-KEY.properties
RUN chmod +x gradlew
RUN rm -rf build/generated
RUN ["./gradlew", "clean", "build", "--stacktrace", "--exclude-task", "test"]

FROM openjdk:11-jdk
COPY --from=build /app/build/libs/runner-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar app.jar
EXPOSE 8080
ENTRYPOINT java -jar app.jar
```

and Jenkins always said "Build Success"

I checked application.yml and application-API-KEY.properties create successfully under {APP}/resources, too.

Please help me... :) Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I found my error in build.gradle.
This problem was caused by 'compileOnly'
I changed my `build.gradle`.

`compileOnly 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial'`

-> `implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-spatial'`

Then it worked properly.